# Отсортировать контейнер по модулю. Как работает sort?

Tags: c++, сортировка

Выполнял задание по отсортировке массива состоящего из целых чисел по модулю.
Решение через функцию abs видел.
До того как обратиться к интернету, попробовал сам и вышло это:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

bool modul(int a, int b) {
    if (a > 0 && b > 0) {
        return (a > b);
    }
    else if (a < 0 && b < 0) {
        if (-1 * a > -1 * b) {
            return (a > b);
        }
        else if (-1 * a < -1 * b) {
            return (a < b);
        }
    }
    else if (a < 0 && b > 0) {
        if (-1 * a > b) {
            return (a > b);
        }
        else if (-1 * a < b) {
            return (a < b);
        }
    }
    else if (a > 0 && b < 0) {
        if (a > -1 * b) {
            return (a > b);
        }
        else if (a < -1 * b) {
            return (a < b);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int q = 0;
    std::cin >> q;
    std::vector<int> modul_sort;
    for (std::size_t index1 = 0; index1 < q; index1++) {
        int n = 0;
        std::cin >> n;
        modul_sort.push_back(n);
    }
    std::sort(modul_sort.begin(), modul_sort.end(), modul);
    for (const auto& item : modul_sort) {
        std::cout << item << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

У меня ничего не получилось. Но вот нет понимания, что именно пошло не так. Я наверное просто не понимаю как работает sort или bool функции или ещё что-то. Прошу, подскажите где я напортачил?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто...

```
std::sort(modul_sort.begin(), modul_sort.end(), 
    [](int a, int b){ return abs(a) < abs(b); });
```

Если вы *не хотите* использовать `abs`, то напишите его самостоятельно. Ну не стоит в любом случае развешивать длинные макароны из `if`'ов...

```
bool modul(int a, int b) 
{
    if (a < 0) a = -a;
    if (b < 0) b = -b;
    return a < b;
}
```

Коротко и вполне понятно.

Comment: Да, через функцию abs я уже видел. Меня просто интересует почему у меня моя реализация не получилась. То есть, что я сделал не так?

Comment: Как минимум, ваша реализация не возвращает "меньше": `if (a > 0 && b > 0) {
        return (a > b);
    }` Еще гляньте дополненный ответ...

Comment: Не возвращает меньше? Я там просто проверял условие того, что оба числа являются положительными и возвращали вроде стандартные a > b. По крайней мере на cppreference вроде, там в примере стояло просто j > i.

Comment: Ещё такой вопрос. Эта функция возвращает только тру, но она не меняет значение переменных. По крайней мере передана не по ссылке.
То есть внутри она меняет знак и делает сравнение, а потом сортирует эту переменную как если бы она была положительной? Это так работает? Вернее ставит условие.

Comment: И большое спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Сортировка всегда выполняется так, как если компаратор выдает отношение "меньше". Если он будет давать "больше" - сортировка будет в порядке убывания. На второй вопрос - я не очень понимаю, что вы хотите спросить. Сортировка выполняется так, чтобы в конечном итоге применение компаратора ко всем рядом стоящим значениям давало true, но еще точнее - чтобы обратное сравнение не давало true :) - cnjzott слева число может быть меньше либо равно стоящего справа. Меньше - в смысле используемого компаратора.

Comment: Премного благодарен! Кажется понял чуток больше. Сомневаюсь конечно, что понял все тонкости, но какие-то идеи в голове точно появились.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно просто читать что пишете. Вот отрывок из вашего кода:

```
 else if (a < 0 && b < 0) {
    if (-1 * a > -1 * b) {
        return (a > b);
    }
```

Словами означает: если `а`  и  `b` имеют отрицательное значение, то в случаи, если `-1 * a > -1 * b`(а это то же самое, что `a < b`) вернуть `(a > b)`. Согласитесь, что это то же самое, что просто вернуть `false`. Никакого сравнения у вас не произойдет. Подобные ошибки у вас почти везде. Вместо этого вы могли бы просто проверить на отрицательность значения  каждого по отдельности и написать:

```
bool modul(int a, int b) {    
    if (a <= 0) {
        if (b >= 0)
            return -a > b;
        else
            return  a < b;
    }
    else {
        if (b < 0)
            return a > -b;
    }
    return a > b;     
}
```

Это если вы хотите сортировать от большего к меньшему. В обратном случаи поменяются знаки в возвращаемом выражении.

Comment: Хм, я думал я ставлю условию и возвращаю правильный ответ(логику) в случае.
То есть при таких-то неких условиях 4 > 3. То есть имеется ввиду, что 4 стоит первее в контейнере.
Но смотря на вашу реализацию что-то в голову мне вроде приходит. Переменная a всегда должна быть больше b?
з.ы. Также жаль, что я и ваш ответ не могу указать как ответ. А поставить плюс не хватает рейтинга. Так что выражу словами благодарность за ваш ответ. Большое спасибо!